# Can anyone help me to get migrate in php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to migrate my tables in newly created laravel project and getting this error but all the container arerunningg fine.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = example_app and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
761▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
762▕             );
763▕         }
764▕     }

  +47 vendor frames 

48  artisan:35
  

Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I was trying that it should migrate my tables from the local to adminer.

Comment: just check your .env file and make sure the `DB_CONNECTION`, `DB_HOST` and other `DB_` config is set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it can't connect to the Database.

In `config/database.php`, check

1. `host`
2. `port`
3. `database`
4. `username`
5. `password`

---

If you're setting it from `.env` check the values are correct. If correct run the below code to clear the config cache.

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` *